# Hibernate performance issue, export is taking hours to download the file. Mean while the browser went out of session

Tags: hibernate

Hibernate performance issue, downloading a file with large amount of data. Mean while the browser went out of session, due to this download status is not updated on browser as session gets timeout from client.

If someone know solution. Please suggest.

Comment: You need to add more information. It is easy to say hibernate has a problem but we need more context and code to provide you an answer

Comment: You have large files stored in the database? The main project in my company was like that when I came aboard. That's never a good idea. I had to write a custom tool in C++ to extract them.